# 2.8 sculpt sphere creates stars?

Tags: sculpting

I'm using the grab tool in sculpt mode on a sphere in the latest 2.8 build. I'm trying to stretch out the top but for some reason it automatically stretches out in 5 directions, creating a star shape. what is this and how do i turn this off?
[image: star?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top right corner, you have a topdown menu called "Symmetry/Lock". In that menu you should have three options called Radial X Y Z like on that picture

[image]

From what I can see on your screencap, you should have Radial X set to 5 like on the picture, try setting it back to 1 and you should be able to sculpt normally

Hope this helped